# Excel: how to transform table into list of records structure

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Given the following table, I'd like to find the highest header number (denoted by `x`'s value in `J4`) and accompanying row index (denoted by `y`'s value in `J5`) which satisfy the input value `I2` with the given tolerance in `J2`:

[image]

As you can spot, there are two values in the table which satisfy the input value and tolerance: cells `F3` and `G3`. However, since the header row number in `G2` is higher (48) than in `F2` (44), we will take `G3` as the final solution, and print out the respective numbers in `J4` and `J5`.

I have a solution using an intermediary matrix with absolute values with the input value subtracted. And then going through each row backwards from `G` to `B` using IF and SMALL in a lengthy formula (very limited and pretty hard-coded).

My wish would be to use modern Excel functions (LAMBDA, MAP, etc) to convert this table into a list of records, and then simply output the according values. Essentially, convert the table into a records structure in-memory, without having an intermediary matrix in the worksheet as follows (transformation examples for `G2`, `G3`, and `E7`):

```
List<Record> vals = [ 
   (36.22, 48, 1),
   (69.31, 48, 2),
   ...
   (169.99, 40, 6),
   ...
]
```

Using this structure, it would then be much easier to simply find the first value in the `vals.[field1]` which is within the input value and tolerance and output the respective List entries for x `vals.[field2]` and y `vals.[field3]`.

Can this be done elegantly using modern Excel functions and in-memory computation?

The input data can be found here: https://pastebin.com/JRaA14e8

|  | 28 | 32 | 36 | 40 | 44 | 48 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23.02 | 25.66 | 28.30 | 30.94 | 33.58 | 36.22 |
| 2 | 42.91 | 48.19 | 53.47 | 58.75 | 64.03 | 69.31 |
| 3 | 62.80 | 70.72 | 78.64 | 86.56 | 94.48 | 102.40 |
| 4 | 82.69 | 93.25 | 103.81 | 114.37 | 124.93 | 135.49 |
| 5 | 102.58 | 115.78 | 128.98 | 142.18 | 155.38 | 168.58 |
| 6 | 122.47 | 138.31 | 154.15 | 169.99 | 185.83 | 201.67 |
| 7 | 142.36 | 160.84 | 179.32 | 197.80 | 216.28 | 234.76 |
| 8 | 162.25 | 183.37 | 204.49 | 225.61 | 246.73 | 267.85 |
| 9 | 182.14 | 205.90 | 229.66 | 253.42 | 277.18 | 300.94 |
| 10 | 202.03 | 228.43 | 254.83 | 281.23 | 307.63 | 334.03 |
| 11 | 221.92 | 250.96 | 280.00 | 309.04 | 338.08 | 367.12 |
| 12 | 241.81 | 273.49 | 305.17 | 336.85 | 368.53 | 400.21 |
| 13 | 261.70 | 296.02 | 330.34 | 364.66 | 398.98 | 433.30 |

---

**Edit 1: Additional background and example**

My original question seems to have lacked in clarity regarding which optimization condition has prevalence and why. This example is a tiny part of an economic viability calculation toolchain for foldable/retractable solar panels. The header row (`1:1`) denotes the number of modules/panels per track, and the (`A:A`) column denotes the number of tracks. So, x actually means modules or panels per track, and y means number of tracks.

In this particular industrial case model, it's always more economic regarding steel support construction to have a higher density of solar panels per track than having more tracks.

When using the tuple (200,3) for (input value, tolerance), three resulting tuples match the selection criteria:

```
(28,10)
(40,7)
(48,6)
```

Since 48 modules/track offers a higher density than 40 or 28, the correct final solution would be x=48 and y=6.

The current situation with the offered solutions is as follows (albeit I probably didn't correctly integrate Redy's solution):

[image]

---

**Edit 2: Working proposed solutions**

It seems there are at least two working solutions:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to get 2 values?

Answer (score 4):

I like INDEX/AGGREGATE.  We can use LET to limit the number of references needing to update:

```
=IFERROR(LET(
    rng,B2:G14,
    trgt,L2,
    tl,L3,
    hd,1:1,
    rw,A:A,
    clm,AGGREGATE(14,7,COLUMN(rng)/(ABS(rng-trgt)<=tl),1),
   rlclm,clm-MIN(COLUMN(rng))+1,
    VSTACK(
        INDEX(hd,clm),
        INDEX(rw,AGGREGATE(14,7,ROW(INDEX(rng,0,rlclm))/(ABS(INDEX(rng,0,rlclm)-trgt)<=tl),1)))),{-1;-1})
```

Note the use of full column and full row in the index part.  We use that so we only need to return the actual column and row and not the relative column and row, less math.

[image]

Comment: Very cool solution, however it does not seem to work entirely correctly. For example, for input=100 and tolerance=3, I'd expect to get 48 and 3; your solution gives me 48 and 4. For input=200 and tolerance=3, I get 48 and 9, instead of the correct solution 48 and 6. Also, where would I add a return of -1 for not found values?

Comment: @ikaerom I am now confused by your outputs results. "For input=200 and tolerance=3, I get 48 and 9, instead of the correct solution 48 and 6." Why should the result be 201.67 instead of 202.03? "For example, for input=100 and tolerance=3, I'd expect to get 48 and 3; your solution gives me 48 and 4" Shouldn't the correct result be 28 and 5?

Comment: @ikaerom see edit

Answer (score 3):

*Note: this answer relies on having the most recent version of Excel for Microsoft 365 (tested) or possibly Excel for the Web (not tested).*

**EDIT to account for "greatest column index" among multiple matches criteria:**

Adjusting the approach to select that match with the largest column header, this should work in cell J4:

```
=LET(
    data, A1:G14,
    row_headers, DROP(TAKE(data, , 1), 1),
    col_headers, DROP(TAKE(data, 1), , 1),
    d, DROP(data, 1, 1),
    v, I2,
    tol, J2,
    cols, COLUMNS(d),
    ascol, TOCOL(d),
    position, SEQUENCE(ROWS(ascol)),
    row, ROUNDUP(position / cols, 0),
    col, MOD(position + cols - 1, cols) + 1,
    arr, HSTACK(ascol, row, col),
    include, BYROW(ascol, LAMBDA(x, AND(x >= (v - tol), x <= (v + tol)))),
    matches, FILTER(arr, include),
    sorted, SORT(matches, {3, 2}, {-1, -1}),
    is_best, TAKE(sorted, 1),
    result, VSTACK(
        INDEX(col_headers, 1, INDEX(is_best, 1, 3)),
        INDEX(row_headers, INDEX(is_best, 1, 2), 1),
        INDEX(is_best, 1, 1)
    ),
    result
)
```

[image]

Or as a LAMBDA:

```
get_best_match = LAMBDA(data, value, tolerance,
    LET(
        //get the headers
        row_headers, DROP(TAKE(data, , 1), 1),
        col_headers, DROP(TAKE(data, 1), , 1),

        //just the search array
        d, DROP(data, 1, 1),
        v, value,
        tol, tolerance,
        cols, COLUMNS(d),

        //convert the array to a column with row and column positions added
        ascol, TOCOL(d),
        position, SEQUENCE(ROWS(ascol)),
        row, ROUNDUP(position / cols, 0),
        col, MOD(position + cols - 1, cols) + 1,
        arr, HSTACK(ascol, row, col),

        //filter for those rows that meet the criteria
        include, BYROW(ascol, LAMBDA(x, AND(x >= (v - tol), x <= (v + tol)))),
        matches, FILTER(arr, include),

        //sort descending on column header, row header
        sorted, SORT(matches, {3, 2}, {-1, -1}),

        //take the first row of the sorted matches
        is_best, TAKE(sorted, 1),

        result, VSTACK(
            INDEX(col_headers, 1, INDEX(is_best, 1, 3)),
            INDEX(row_headers, INDEX(is_best, 1, 2), 1),
            INDEX(is_best, 1, 1)
        ),
        result
    )
);
```

**Original answer before new criteria added:**

I believe this will work in cell J4:

```
=LET(
    data, A1:G14,
    row_headers, DROP(TAKE(data, , 1), 1),
    col_headers, DROP(TAKE(data, 1), , 1),
    d, DROP(data, 1, 1),
    v, I2,
    tol, J2,
    cols, COLUMNS(d),
    matches, MAP(d, LAMBDA(x, AND(x >= (v - tol), x <= (v + tol)))),
    is_best, d = MAX(d * matches),
    best_position, MAX(is_best * SEQUENCE(ROWS(d), cols)),
    y, ROUNDUP(best_position / cols, 0),
    x, MOD(best_position + cols - 1, cols) + 1,
    result, VSTACK(
        INDEX(col_headers, 1, x),
        INDEX(row_headers, y, 1),
        MAX(d * matches)
    ),
    result
)
```

[image]

We can annotate and save it in the Advanced Formula Environment as a named LAMBDA like this:

```
get_headers = LAMBDA(data,test,tolerance,
    LET(
        //get just the row index from column 1, rows 2:max
        row_headers, DROP(TAKE(data, , 1), 1),

        //get just the column headers from row 1, columns 2:max
        col_headers, DROP(TAKE(data, 1), , 1),

        //get just the array of data to test against
        d, DROP(data, 1, 1),

        //get the number of columns in the array (the )
        cols, COLUMNS(d),

        //test each value against the boundaries
        matches, MAP(d, LAMBDA(x, AND(x >= (test - tolerance), x <= (test + tolerance)))),

        //identify the best value
        is_best, d = MAX(d * matches),

        //find the position of the best value
        best_position, MAX(is_best * SEQUENCE(ROWS(d), cols)),

        //identify the row index
        y, ROUNDUP(best_position / cols, 0),

        //identify the column index
        x, MOD(best_position + cols - 1, cols) + 1,

        //return the column header, the row header and the best value
        result, VSTACK(
            INDEX(col_headers, 1, x),
            INDEX(row_headers, y, 1),
            MAX(d * matches)
        ),
        result
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks, another cool solution, but not entirely correct: 200 with tolerance 3 should return the tuple 48 and 6.

Comment: @ikaerom "200 with tolerance 3 should return the tuple 48 and 6", why? Shouldn't 28 and 10 be correct (202.03 instead of 201.67)?

Comment: Not quite. Maybe, I should tighten my optimization criteria description. For input (200, 3) we have three possible tuples that match: (28,10), (40,7), and (48,6). All of their lookup values in the matrix are within 200±3. Due to the nature of the optimization (I'll outline it better above in my question), I need to take the highest matching header row number, which is 48, since 48 is higher than 40, or 28.

Comment: It's difficult to determine what *correct* is if it's not specified. Nevertheless, I've made an adjustment and edited my answer, @ikaerom

Comment: Thanks again for the update. It's much appreciated. It's difficult to determine what to specify, if it's unclear what's missing. The original specification to me clearly stated what I have amended now in the "Edit 1" section. Specifically, in the second paragraph, which commences with "As you can spot ...". I hope my "Edit 1" section now made it even clearer. Your revised solution seems correct, from my limited testing.

Comment: Some of the functions you're using are not yet available for majority of the users, many of us just don't yet have the latest version of Excel for various reasons. It worth mentioning prerequisite of running your solution.

Comment: OK, thanks @ikaerom. If the formula / function I posted answers the question, please mark the answer accepted.

Comment: @MátéJuhász good point. I've added an italicized comment at the beginning of my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. We find the largest number using a combination of `LARGE`, `MAP` and `LAMBDA` functions.

```
=LARGE(($B$2:$G$14)*(--MAP($B$2:$G$14,LAMBDA(r,AND($I$2-$J$2<=r,$I$2+$J$2>=r)))),1)
```

[image]

- `MAP($B$2:$G$14,LAMBDA(r,AND($I$2-$J$2<=r,$I$2+$J$2>=r)))`: returns an array of TRUE or FALSE based on whether the numbers in the array are inside the tolerance value.

[image]

- `($B$2:$G$14)*(--MAP($B$2:$G$14,LAMBDA(r,AND($I$2-$J$2<=r,$I$2+$J$2>=r))))`: We then multiply the results of the previous formula with our array (which has been are now 1s and 0s due to `--`) to only numbers that obey the criteria.

- `LARGE(($B$2:$G$14)*(--MAP($B$2:$G$14,LAMBDA(r,AND($I$2-$J$2<=r,$I$2+$J$2>=r)))),1)`: returns the largest number that fits the criteria.

2. We use the largest number as our criteria to return x and y

- x formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B1:G1,,SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$G$14=J5)*COLUMN($B$2:$G$14))-@COLUMN($B$2:$G$14)+1),-1)
```

[image]

- y formula:

```
=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$G$14=J5)*ROW($B$2:$G$14))-@ROW($B$2:$G$14)+1,-1)
```

[image]

The formulae for x and y are adapted from the ones described by this article: [Get location of value in 2D array](https://exceljet.net/formulas/get-location-of-value-in-2d-array)].

Both formulae will return `-1`, if nothing is found.

The values must be unique as noted [here](https://exceljet.net/formulas/get-location-of-value-in-2d-array):

> note these formulas will fail if there are duplicate values in the array

Comment: This also looks interesting, but I couldn't get it to work on my side. Also, I'd like to have a solution without an intermediary matrix. I got the "result" part working, but the x and y always return -1 on my side.